# Как в VK загрузить картинку python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, requests, вконтакте

Адрес сервера я получаю "photos.getWallUploadServer".
Картинку отправляю на полученный "upload_url"

```
files = {'photo': open(path, 'rb')}
requests.post(upload_link, files=files, timeout=10).json()
```

Но сервер возвращает пустую "photo".
Подозреваю, что не хватает mime types, но не знаю как их добавлять. Подскажите пожалуйста, как корректно отправить картинку в ВК.

Comment: Какое значение имеет переменная `path`?

Comment: @andreymal Путь к картинке 1.jpg. Перед этим еще проверка if exist(path)

Comment: Если `.jpg` в конце пути вправду есть, то тогда это всё странно

Comment: Проверьте сигнатуру файла `print(open(path, 'rb').read(16))` — действительно ли это JPEG-картинка?

Comment: @andreymal
Это точно jpg, я ее скачивал руками, это тестовая картинка. 
я посмотрел примеры на PHP, там помимо картинки отправляют mime types. Или оно на python должно и так рабтать?

Comment: Если есть корректное имя файла, то всё должно работать и так (ну по крайней раньше проблем вроде не возникало). Проверьте сигнатуру, вдруг картинка на самом деле не jpg

Comment: Если очень хочется, можно попробовать прописать mime-тип вручную: `files = {'photo': ('1.jpg', open(path, 'rb'), 'image/jpeg')}` — но я подозреваю, что это ничего особо не изменит